# Get position relative to parent dropped object Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm having an issue with drag & drop jQuery UI:

**I have this html:**

```
<div class="outfit-wrapper">

    <div id="outfit-area"> <!-- drop to this area -->
        <div class="outfits"> <!--store images (and content) in this div -->
        </div> 

        <div class="toolbox-area"> <!-- functions (buttons) for outfit-area -->
            <img src="forward.png" class="button forward" alt="forward outfit" /> <!--forward selected outfitimage up (zindex +1), button-class for positioning-->
            <img src="backward.png" class="button backward" alt="backward outfit"/> <!--backward selected outfitimage down (zindex -1), button-class for positioning -->
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div id="products-area"> <!-- drag from this area -->
        <!-- examples products -->
        <div class="ui-draggable">prod1</div> 
        <div class="ui-draggable">prod2</div>
        <div class="ui-draggable">prod3</div>
        <div class="ui-draggable">prod4</div>
        <div class="ui-draggable">prod5</div>
    </div>

</div> <!--end outfit-wrapper-->
```

**And this jQuery-code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Drag FROM - area
$( "#products-area .ui-draggable" ).draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    containment: ".outfit-wrapper", 
    option: "stack",//Comes over everything other objects when dragged
    revert: "invalid" //Revert will only occur if the draggable has not been dropped on a droppable.
});

//Drop TO - area
$( "#outfit-area").droppable({

    accept: "#products-area .ui-draggable", //Must come from this dragged element
    drop: function( event, ui ) {

        //Put content from dragged object into of a new <span> n #outfit-area
        var currentPos = ui.helper.position();
        var posLeft = parseInt(currentPos.left);
        var posTop = parseInt(currentPos.top);

        var draggedObj = ui.draggable.html(); //Get HTML-content of draggable

        //Add a span and a div
        var newContent = '<div class="outfit" style="position:absolute;left:' + posLeft + 'px;top:' + posTop + 'px;">'+draggedObj;
        newContent = newContent + '<span class="close-outfit">X</span>'; //Add a close-button for each dragged content
        newContent = newContent + '</div>';

        $(this).find(".outfits").append(newContent); //HOWTO: Get relative position of 


    }
});


}); //End onready (DOM is loaded)
```

**What I want to do is:**

When a user drags the `<div class="ui-draggable">prod{nr}</div>` - I want it to be included in the dom for the div **#outfit-area** and a span should be included into that div.

posLeft and posTop only gets the value relative from the original position from the dragged element.

**How do I get the get position of dropped element relative to the new parent #outfit-area** ?

Is there an alternative way of doing this? I've googled around and I can find a lot of similar questions, but not this particular one. I'm probably missing something very obvious, but then give me some pointers :-)

**UPDATE:** (New question arrives)
I've found the problem. It was actually a CSS-issue:

**My css:**

```
.outfit-wrapper {position:relative;height:800px;width:100%;}
#outfit-area {position:relative;float:left;margin-right:50px;width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000000;}
.outfits {position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;}
.toolbox-area {position:absolute;top:0;right:0;height:40px;width:60px;border:1px solid #ff0000;}

#products-area div {display:block;float:left;width:40px;}
#products-area {float:left;width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000000;background:red;}
```

When setting position:relative on #products-area:

```
#products-area {position:relative;float:left;width:300px;height:200px;border:1px solid #000000;background:red;}
```

The dragged element returns the wrong positions when dropped. **Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried getting the position of the actual element after the drop?

```
var pos = ui.draggable.position();
var posLeft = pos.left;
var posTop = pos.top;
```

Comment: Then I get positions where the new div is created. I want positions where the original div is dropped.

Comment: Have a look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qsYf7/ The two console.log entries should show both the relative position of the dropped element to #outfit-area and also the original dragged element

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot! You've got me thinking! I deleted all my css and then it worked, I tried again and I'm now 100% sure what the problem is, but I don't understand why. Read my updated question.